# python re: Need to replace numbers with links to websites

Tags: python, python-re

I have a strings like this:

> this is SBN: 1245897 some text some text SBN4589364 some text some
> text SBN-7859157, some text some text Part Num: 2615, some text SBN:7859148 asasas
> YYY-485 some text some text...

I need to get all SBN related numbers only and replace it with links to some site, i'm trying this code, but that's does not work

```
p = re.compile('SBN[:- ] ( \d+ )')
p.sub(r'<a href="http://example.com/?sbn=\1" target="_blank">\1</a>', string)
```

Please help..

Comment: With a tiny bit of debugging, your regex should read `SBN[:- ] ?(\d+)`, or something fairly close. You sprinkled in some spaces you didn't want to match and the space after the first symbol is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All whitespace counts in a regular expression! Only include whitespace exactly when you would want whitespace in your match as well. You can limit it to just spaces ( ), but generally 'all whitespace' is more useful (`\s`).

I would also suggest always writing a regular expression as a raw string.

This regex catches all examples in your question:

```
p = re.compile(r'SBN[:-]\s*(\d+)')
```

Comment: It works!..but it replaces 'SBN' as well.. so string became 'some text <a href="..455689784">455689784</a> some text...' instead 'some text SBN: <a href="..455689784">455689784</a> some text...'

Comment: @EduVMagadan That was the replacement pattern you chose... Add SBN inside the `<a>` tag in the replacement pattern if you don't want to remove it.